# ec2 Instance refused to connect in browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created my ec2 instance successfully in AWS.

here my instance end point is `ec2-18-222-211-176.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

The problem is when I try to hit this end point it is showing refused to connect. I don't have any Idea  why it is not working like this

where as I successfully connect instance using `SSH key`, here it is working fine.

here my instance security group inbound rules are listed below

[image: inbound security rules]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is working on both the DNS and the public IP http://18.222.211.176

[image: See this screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It was the Apache web server not running. To find this, type this from your root@ip directory:

```
service httpd status
```

To start the server, type:

```
service httpd start
```